# Css bem block inside block naming

Tags: css, bem

HTML layout

```
<div class="site-header">
  <ul class="site-header__social social"> <!-- block -->
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <ul class="post__social social"> <!-- block -->
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="site-footer">
  <ul class="site-footer__social social"> <!-- block -->
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The layout just a example, we add `social` class to each of social list.

Each social block have different style, we can not just use `social` class at css file.

So i dont need add block class to the social and only use element class `site-header__social`, but what if i want it to be a block class? any suggest to name it by block class?  thanks.

Comment: block is a element of css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may still call it `social` and also add a modifier to describe differences in styling. So it'd be like this:

```
<div class="site-header">
  <ul class="site-header__social social social_type_header"> <!-- block -->
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <ul class="post__social social social_type_post"> <!-- block -->
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="site-footer">
  <ul class="site-footer__social social social_type_footer"> <!-- block -->
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
    <li class="social__li">social icon here</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```